# Visualization library for disjoint intervals

Tags: r, memory, shiny, data-visualization, strace

I want to visualize memory mapping states of processes. For this I parsed the output of

```
# strace -s 256 -v -k -f -e trace=memory,process command
```

and now I have a time series of disjoint sums of intervals on the real line. Is there a convenient visualization library for such data? Haskell interface would be the most time-saving for me, but any suggestion is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Asking for libraries is kinda off topic here, but did you take a look at [haskell-chart](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Chart)

Comment: @epsilonhalbe: Thanks, it looks good.  What would be the correct terminology(or tags) for this? I thought this should be a common scenario and there would be a ready made solution.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe: Does asking for a terminology/theory instead of a library make this more suitable here?

Comment: Another nice library for plotting I used is `QuickPlot`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickPlot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case this might be useful for anyone, I hacked up a little tool to do this. (By the way I ended up using R/Shiny for interactive visualization.)

Here's the github [repo](https://github.com/nishiuramakoto/vismem).
[image: screenshot]

It's interactive in that if you click a region, the stack traces responsible for the memory mapping
will be shown like this:

```
trace:
 22695 mmap(NULL, 251658240, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x2b4210000000
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so(mmap64+0xa) [0xf487a]
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(_ZN2os17pd_reserve_memoryEmPcm+0x31) [0x91e9c1]
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(_ZN2os14reserve_memoryEmPcm+0x20) [0x91ced0]
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(_ZN13ReservedSpace10initializeEmmbPcmb+0x256) [0xac20a6]
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(_ZN17ReservedCodeSpaceC1Emmb+0x2c) [0xac270c]
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(_ZN8CodeHeap7reserveEmmm+0xa5) [0x61a3c5]
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(_ZN9CodeCache10initializeEv+0x80) [0x47ff50]
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(_Z12init_globalsv+0x45) [0x63c905]
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(_ZN7Threads9create_vmEP14JavaVMInitArgsPb+0x23e) [0xa719be]
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(JNI_CreateJavaVM+0x74) [0x6d11c4]
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so(JavaMain+0x9e) [0x745e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so(start_thread+0xc4) [0x8184]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so(clone+0x6d) [0xfa37d]
```

The same colors correspond to the same flags for mmap/msync/madvise etc.

## Synopsis

```
$ make show-prerequisites
# (Follow the instructions)

$ make COMMAND="time ls"
...
DATA_DIR=build/data-2016-12-12_02h38m13s
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5000
....
$ firefox http://127.0.0.1:5000

$ # Re-browse the previous results
$ make DATA_DIR=build/data-2016-12-12_02h38m13s
```

In the process of development I realized the striking geometricity of the problem.
So I created a module called `Sheaf` and described there a recipe for defining a Grothendieck
topology and a constant sheaf on it. It now seems the Grothendieck (or Lawvere-Tierney) topologies
are actually ubiquitous for programming.. but I'm not sure if it will prove anything worthy.
So feel free to check it!